# On checkbox change, find and check another checkbox and modify the values of some text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

I have created a function that checks other checkboxes on change. the function works but there is an error showing in console and the performance of the click is slow.

the issue comes from the `.change();` . I have added this at the end in conditional statement, so that the values of the text inputs change dynamically.

Now if i remove the  `.change();` from follwoing, it works ok but then the values of the text inputs won't change.

```js
      if(this.checked) {
          //Do stuff
          $(this).closest('.multiple_checboxes_sets').find(".sms_groups [data-group='" + name + "']").prop( "checked", true ).change();
      } else {
          $(this).closest('.multiple_checboxes_sets').find(".sms_groups [data-group='" + name + "']").prop( "checked", false ).change();
      }
```

the whole code  **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nashza/L6as438r/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".group_checkbox_all").change(function() {

    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.group_checkbox').prop("checked", true).change();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.group_checkbox').prop("checked", false).change();
    }
  });


  $(".group_checkbox").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).data('group');
    var checked = $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.group_checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).val()
    }).get();
    var notchecked = $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.group_checkbox:not(:checked)').map(function() {
      return $(this).val()
    }).get();
    var checkedtext = $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.group_checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).data('group')
    }).get();
    var notcheckedtext = $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.group_checkbox:not(:checked)').map(function() {
      return $(this).data('group')
    }).get();


    $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.lbu_multilistsvalue').val(checked).change();
    $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.lbu_currentvalue').val(notchecked).change();
    $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.lbu_multiliststext').val(checkedtext).change();
    $(this).closest('.group_checboxes_set').find('.lbu_currenttags').val(notcheckedtext).change();


    if (this.checked) {
      //Do stuff
      $(this).closest('.multiple_checboxes_sets').find(".sms_groups [data-group='" + name + "']").prop("checked", true).change();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.multiple_checboxes_sets').find(".sms_groups [data-group='" + name + "']").prop("checked", false).change();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiple_checboxes_sets">

  <div class="group_checboxes_set">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox_all" data-group="All" id="all" type="checkbox" value="0000" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 1" id="1111" type="checkbox" value="1111" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="1111">Box 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 2" id="2222" type="checkbox" value="22222" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="2222">Box 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 3" id="3333" type="checkbox" value="3333" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="3333">Box 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 4" id="4444" type="checkbox" value="4444" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="4444">Box 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 5" id="55555" type="checkbox" value="5555" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="55555">Box 5</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multilistsvalue" id="lbu_multilistsvalue" name="lbu_multilistsvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currentvalue" id="lbu_currentvalue" name="lbu_currentvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multiliststext" id="lbu_multiliststext" name="lbu_multiliststext">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currenttags" id="lbu_currenttags" name="lbu_currenttags" value="">

  </div>


  <div class="group_checboxes_set sms_groups">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox_all" data-group="All" id="all1" type="checkbox" value="aaaa" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="all1">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 1" id="11112" type="checkbox" value="bbbb" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="11112">Box 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 2" id="22223" type="checkbox" value="cccc" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="22223">Box 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 3" id="33334" type="checkbox" value="dddd" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="33334">Box 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 4" id="44445" type="checkbox" value="eeee" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="44445">Box 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox" data-group="Box 5" id="555556" type="checkbox" value="ffff" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="555556">Box 5</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multilistsvalue" id="lbu_multilistsvalue1" name="lbu_multilistsvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currentvalue" id="lbu_currentvalue1" name="lbu_currentvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multiliststext" id="lbu_multiliststext1" name="lbu_multiliststext">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currenttags" id="lbu_currenttags1" name="lbu_currenttags" value="">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use `.trigger( "change" );` to get ride of errors. And as per performance issue, I'm not surprised at all with all this triggers going on. I have a feeling this it could be done much more simpler. As just adding/copying/removing values around.

Comment: @ikiK I have tried `.trigger( "change" );` it didn't help as well. I am sure there should be a better way to do this, still trying..

Comment: what do you mean it didn't help? It removed the errors for me, I tried it also.

Comment: @ikiK I tried here: https://jsfiddle.net/Nashza/L6as438r/4/

Comment: SO snippet removed errors, I just tried this locally and I got `Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion`. You need to change your logic. To many events like I said before.

Comment: Or there is a loop somewhere, I think its this line judging from an error: `$(this).closest('.multiple_checboxes_sets').find(".sms_groups [data-group='" + name + "']").prop("checked", true).change();`

Comment: and `var checked` is loop too. Console log it.

Comment: @ikiK i cosole.log the `var checked`, looks like a loop yes 800+ logs

Comment: @ikiK i think i have to change this `$(".group_checkbox").change(function() {`   to this 
 `$(".group_checkbox").on("click", function() {` . but still need to find a way to change the other inputs values

Comment: I think its a colossal mistake to invoke change event inside change listeners. You have to many of those.  I think you need to re-think your logic completely. And avoid using  invoked change events or completely minimize it. You are getting to many loops and I don't know from where.

Comment: @ikiK how do you propose to get the same approach working? with minimum code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 

> *how do you propose to get the same approach working? with minimum code*

- 

Well you got me thinking how to, started playing around and things got little out of hand hehe.

So minimum code part is out of the game for now :) .

Not quite finished as I don't understand what was the main goal. But most of it is working. And no chnage and click events what soever invoked manually. Its all based on arrays and pure JS.

And given your version is not working properly (looping problem) I will share this, hope it helps in understadning how to achive this in other way.

```js
var group1 = [];
var group2 = [];
var group1Box = [];
var group2Box = [];
var itemvalue = [];
var itemvalue2 = [];
var itemBox = [];




//GROUP_CHECKBOX
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].group_checkbox').forEach(item => {
  // GET ALL VALUES AND BOXES
  if (item.classList.contains("group1") === true) {
    group1.push(item.value);
    group1Box.push(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
  }
  if (item.classList.contains("group2") === true) {
    group2.push(item.value);
    group2Box.push(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
  }

  // ADD EventListener TO ALL CHECKBOX 
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    //IF GROUP1 CHECKBOX IS CHECKED
    if (item.checked === true && item.classList.contains("group1") === true) {
      itemvalue.push(item.value);
      itemvalue2.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-group="' + item.getAttribute('data-group') + '"]')[1].value);
      itemBox.push(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
      group1 = group1.filter(group1 => !itemvalue.includes(group1));
      group2 = group2.filter(group2 => !itemvalue2.includes(group2));
      group1Box = group1Box.filter(group1Box => !itemBox.includes(group1Box));
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue").value = itemvalue;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue").value = group1;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags").value = group1Box;

      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-group="' + item.getAttribute('data-group') + '"]')[1].checked = true;

      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = itemvalue2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = group2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = group1Box;
    }

    //IF GROUP1 CHECKBOX IS UN-CHECKED
    if (item.checked === false && item.classList.contains("group1") === true) {
      group1.push(item.value);
      itemvalue = itemvalue.filter(itemvalue => !item.value.includes(itemvalue))
      group2.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-group="' + item.getAttribute('data-group') + '"]')[1].value);
      itemvalue2 = itemvalue2.filter(itemvalue2 => !document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-group="' + item.getAttribute('data-group') + '"]')[1].value.includes(itemvalue2))
      group1Box.push(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
      itemBox = itemBox.filter(itemBox => !item.getAttribute('data-group').includes(itemBox))
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue").value = itemvalue;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue").value = group1;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags").value = group1Box;

      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-group="' + item.getAttribute('data-group') + '"]')[1].checked = false;


      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = itemvalue2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = group2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = group1Box;
    }
    //IF GROUP2 CHECKBOX IS CHECKED
    if (item.checked === true && item.classList.contains("group2") === true) {
      itemvalue2.push(item.value);
      itemBox.push(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
      group2 = group2.filter(group2 => !itemvalue2.includes(group2));
      group1Box = group1Box.filter(group1Box => !itemBox.includes(group1Box));
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = itemvalue2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = group2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = group1Box;
    }
    //IF GROUP2 CHECKBOX IS UN-CHECKED
    if (item.checked === false && item.classList.contains("group2") === true) {
      group2.push(item.value);
      itemvalue2 = itemvalue2.filter(itemvalue2 => !item.value.includes(itemvalue2))
      group1Box.push(item.getAttribute('data-group'));
      itemBox = itemBox.filter(itemBox => !item.getAttribute('data-group').includes(itemBox))
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = itemvalue2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = group2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = group1Box;
    }


  })

})



//GROUP_CHECKBOX_ALL
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].group_checkbox_all').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (item.checked === true && item.classList.contains("group1all") === true) {
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].group_checkbox').forEach(item2 => {
        item2.checked = true;
      })
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue").value = itemvalue;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue").value = group1;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags").value = group1Box;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = itemvalue2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = group2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = group1Box;
    }
    if (item.checked === false && item.classList.contains("group1all") === true) {
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].group_checkbox').forEach(item2 => {
        item2.checked = false;
      })
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = "";
    }

    if (item.checked === true && item.classList.contains("group2all") === true) {
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].group_checkbox.group2').forEach(item2 => {
        item2.checked = true;
      })
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = itemvalue2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = group2;
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = itemBox;
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = group1Box;
    }
    if (item.checked === false && item.classList.contains("group2all") === true) {
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].group_checkbox').forEach(item2 => {
        item2.checked = false;
      })
      document.getElementById("lbu_multilistsvalue1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_currentvalue1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_multiliststext1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("lbu_currenttags1").value = "";
    }



  })

})
```

```html
<div class="multiple_checboxes_sets">

  <div class="group_checboxes_set">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox_all group1all" data-group="All" id="all" type="checkbox" value="0000" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group1" data-group="Box 1" id="1111" type="checkbox" value="1111" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="1111">Box 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group1" data-group="Box 2" id="2222" type="checkbox" value="22222" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="2222">Box 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group1" data-group="Box 3" id="3333" type="checkbox" value="3333" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="3333">Box 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group1" data-group="Box 4" id="4444" type="checkbox" value="4444" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="4444">Box 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group1" data-group="Box 5" id="55555" type="checkbox" value="5555" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="55555">Box 5</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multilistsvalue" id="lbu_multilistsvalue" name="lbu_multilistsvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currentvalue" id="lbu_currentvalue" name="lbu_currentvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multiliststext" id="lbu_multiliststext" name="lbu_multiliststext">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currenttags" id="lbu_currenttags" name="lbu_currenttags" value="">

  </div>


  <div class="group_checboxes_set sms_groups">

    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox_all group2all" data-group="All" id="all1" type="checkbox" value="aaaa" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="all1">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group2" data-group="Box 1" id="11112" type="checkbox" value="bbbb" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="11112">Box 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group2" data-group="Box 2" id="22223" type="checkbox" value="cccc" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="22223">Box 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group2" data-group="Box 3" id="33334" type="checkbox" value="dddd" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="33334">Box 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group2" data-group="Box 4" id="44445" type="checkbox" value="eeee" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="44445">Box 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="group_checkbox group2" data-group="Box 5" id="555556" type="checkbox" value="ffff" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="555556">Box 5</label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multilistsvalue" id="lbu_multilistsvalue1" name="lbu_multilistsvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currentvalue" id="lbu_currentvalue1" name="lbu_currentvalue">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_multiliststext" id="lbu_multiliststext1" name="lbu_multiliststext">
    <input type="text" class="form-control lbu_currenttags" id="lbu_currenttags1" name="lbu_currenttags" value="">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It works Great. I have been working on the issue the whole day. Thanks dear!

Comment: @Nash Glad it helps. I think there are some issues with deselecting after selecting all, or some combination of those, arrays are not updating. But its 1am here, maybe ill take a look tomorrow.

Comment: I have managed to make it work as expected but had to recreate the code again https://jsfiddle.net/Nashza/u6zs1t9c/6/